# Is there an offline Google docs app?

Tags: software-recommendation, google

Are there any desktop apps for Google Docs on Ubuntu 12.04? I need to be able to edit docs offline and save them so they auto-sync to my account when I get an internet connection.

Comment: Edit them in Libreeoffice then upload them to Google Docs?...

Comment: I've not tried this myself: [ooo2gd --- Export your documents to Google Docs, Zoho and WebDAV servers from OpenOffice.org](http://code.google.com/p/ooo2gd/)

Comment: you are looking for something like Google Drive, right?

Comment: you could try [Insync](http://insynchq.com). it's not free, but it's a really solid product.

Answer (score 4):

Option 1)
For offline access, open Chrome. Click the Google Docs app icon or visit https://docs.google.com The offline version of your Documents List will load.

You may need to add google docs to your Chrome -
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf

Option 2)
Use a text editor - gedit or LibreOffice, edit the document(s) then save them in your Documents folder.  Then, when on-line again copy the info into a google doc.

Comment: The offline version that is accessible after installing the extension is _view-only_.

Comment: Really? View-only is not very useful.

Comment: Comment 1 is no longer accurate; docs are editable if you enable offline editing via https://drive.google.com/drive/settings first.

Answer (score 0):

https://launchpad.net/gwoffice

GWOffice might be something that you are looking for.

Comment: It is a great tool, but only available up to Ubuntu 12.04.